# Android ViewPager: Recursive entry to executePendingTransactions with no nested fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am using a ViewPager on my application, and it works OK except then showing the last fragment.
When that fragment is displayed I am receiving the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Recursive entry to executePendingTransactions
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1388)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:431)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:139)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:804)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.completeScroll(ViewPager.java:1280)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.computeScroll(ViewPager.java:1176)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14182)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14239)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15017)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3298)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3135)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14192)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14239)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15017)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3298)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3135)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15306)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:472)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14197)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14239)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15017)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3298)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3135)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14192)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14239)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15017)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3298)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3135)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15306)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:472)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2568)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14197)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14239)
at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.buildDisplayList(HardwareRenderer.java:1570)
at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:1449)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2705)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2571)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2143)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1234)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6467)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:803)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:603)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:573)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:789)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Reading several stackoverflow questions, the most common cause of this is to have nested fragments. However, this is not my case and none of my fragments contains a sub fragment.
To populate the ViewPager I am using a PageAdapter as follows:

```
    // step 1: create the fragment list
    List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
    // wt1
    WalkthroughFragment fragment = new WalkthroughFragment_();
    fragment.setImageBottomId(R.drawable.wt1);
    fragment.setTextId(R.string.walkthrough_1);
    fragment.setButtonId(R.string.walkthrough_skip);
    fragments.add(fragment);
    // wt2
    fragment = new WalkthroughFragment_();
    fragment.setImageBottomId(R.drawable.wt2);
    fragment.setTextId(R.string.walkthrough_2);
    fragments.add(fragment);
    // login
    LoginSocialFragment social = new LoginSocialFragment_();
    fragments.add(social);

    // step 2: create the adapter for the view pager
    this.pager.setAdapter(new MyPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments));
    // step 3: set the default item as the first one
    //TODO: use preferences to see whether should be the last one
    this.pager.setCurrentItem(0);
    //step 4: bind the pager to the indicator
    this.indicator.setViewPager(this.pager);
    this.indicator.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Then I am not using these fragments on any other part of my code, nor adding them again.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It ended up being a problem with the last fragment.
When that fragment was loaded by the ViewPager, it threw a ClassDefNotFound exception due to a missing jar.
Then, since I was reloading the activity, the fragment was instantiated again and failed throwing the exception that I put on my post.
So the "Recursive entry to executePendingTransactions" exception is not always about nested fragments. Just so you know :)

Answer (score 0):

So, I was having the same problem.
No nested fragments at all and not even a ViewPager.
My app was working fine when suddenly this begun.

After seeing this your answer to your problem I changed my Log filters to Warnings from Selected Applications.
And It turns out that a simple "Array Out Of Bounds Exception" (Warning) was being thrown somewhere in a Fragment. After fixing it, the "Recursive entry to executePendingTransactions" stopped.

I didn't research or anything. But it seems that anything that makes a fragment "freeze" can be the cause of this.
If someone is having this problem, I strongly suggest to do what I did to find the problem (change the log filter).